# Need Clarification on Correctly Saving Uploaded File Data to Default Storage using Django-minio-storage?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-models, minio

I've received a response that has been helpful so far, and everything has been functioning as expected. However, I've encountered some confusion when attempting to save uploaded file data to the default storage.

In my current implementation, I have a method named `_save_uploaded_file_data`, which ideally should handle the task of saving uploaded file data to the default storage. This comes after successfully uploading the file to MinIO using a presigned URL. Here's the relevant excerpt of my code:

Although my code appears straightforward, I'm uncertain about the accuracy of my approach, particularly when it comes to saving the uploaded file data to the default storage, which could potentially be local storage. I would greatly appreciate guidance, insights, or suggestions on the proper way to handle this situation. If you could provide any tips, relevant code snippets, or best practices related to this scenario, it would be immensely helpful. Thank you.

models.py

```py
class FileModel(models.Model):
    uploaded_file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads)
```

minio.py

```py
class MinioUploader:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.client = default_storage.client
        self.bucket_name = settings.MINIO_STORAGE_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME
        self.file = file
        self.put_presigned_url = self._get_put_presigned_url()

    def _get_put_presigned_url(self):
        return self.client.presigned_put_object(
            self.bucket_name,
            self.tus_file.filename,
            expires=timedelta(minutes=2),
        )

    def upload_file(self, file_path):
        file_data = self._read_file_data(file_path)
        response = self._upload_to_presigned_url(file_data)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            self._save_uploaded_file_data(file_data)

        return response

    def _read_file_data(self, file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
            file_data = file.read()
        return file_data

    def _upload_to_presigned_url(self, file_data):
        headers = {
            'Cache-Control': settings.MINIO_STORAGE_MEDIA_OBJECT_METADATA.get(
                'Cache-Control'
            ),
        }

        response = requests.put(
            self.put_presigned_url,
            data=file_data,
            headers=headers,
        )
        return response

    def _save_uploaded_file_data(self, file_data):
        uploaded_file_name = self.file.filename
        uploaded_file_path = f"{settings.MEDIA_URL}{uploaded_file_name}"

        # Save the uploaded file data to a local file
        with default_storage.open(uploaded_file_path, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(file_data)

        print(f"Uploaded file data saved: {uploaded_file_path}")
```